# what would be the equivalent of dot net + flex in PHP + javascript world?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I would like to develop a web based application which gives user a desktop like experience.
I have seen a couple of applications use dot net + flex to give this experience.

My question is : is there a php + javascript + html5 + css3 equivalent of this ?
Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also look at [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/). The backend can be any language you want.

Comment: this one is the closest to a desktop / flex like environment. Other one is Cappucino(http://cappuccino.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/), it takes care of User Interface for you and it's a PHP library.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Ext](http://www.extjs.com/) framework. Check out some examples [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/). Be sure to see the "Desktop" sample.

Comment: any other framework with more flexible license like MIT or BSD.  I have know ext for ages but always scared to use it because of the GPL licence.

Answer (score 0):

If you have experience with flex you can always use flex and connect to php on the backend. Using [AMFPHP](http://projects.silexlabs.org/?/amfphp) you can store and access any of your data objects easily.